# Issues scripting out SSAS Tabular roles via PowerShell

Tags: ssas-tabular

I am trying to create a Powershell script which will output SSAS Tabular Roles and I am having some difficulties. I have searched online for help and have found some code which seems to be reasonably widespread but for some reason is not working for me. The code is below

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular”) > $NULL

$Server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server

If ($? -eq $False)

{

      Throw “Cannot load assembly”

      EXIT

}

# SSAS server name variable
$SSASServerName = "."

# Try to connect to the SSAS server
$SSASServer = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$SSASServer.Connect($SSASServerName)

# Object to store the result
$Result = @()

# Get the SSAS databases and loop thru each of them
foreach ($DB in $SSASServer.Databases)
{
    # Get the SSAS database
    $SSASDatabase = $SSASServer.Databases.Item($DB.ID)

    # Get the roles available within the SSAS database and loop thru each of them
    foreach ($Role in $SSASDatabase.Roles)
    {
        # Get the members within the role and loop thru each one of them
        foreach ($UserName in $Role.Members)
        {
            # Create a new object that would store the database name, role name and member user name
            $ItemResult = New-Object System.Object
            $ItemResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name DatabaseName -value $DB.Name
            $ItemResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name RoleName -value $Role.Name
            $ItemResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name UserName -value $UserName.Name

            # Put the item result and append it to the result object
            $Result +=$ItemResult
        }
    }
}
```

when I run this it doesn't return any errors but doesn't give me any roles and there are many roles in the SSAS DBs that are on the server. It seems to return an empty set for the Roles property.

Can someone help point me in the direction I'm going wrong please?

Thanks in advance
Mike

Answer (score 0):

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")

$FormatEnumerationLimit = -1

# SSAS server name variable
$SSASServerName = "SERVERNAME\TABULAR"


# Try to connect to the SSAS server
$SSASServer = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$SSASServer.Connect($SSASServerName)

# Object to store the result
$Result = @()

# Get the SSAS databases and loop thru each of them
foreach ($DB in $SSASServer.Databases)
{
     # Get the SSAS database
     $SSASDatabase = $SSASServer.Databases.Item($DB.name)
     
     foreach ($Role in $SSASDatabase.Roles)
     {
          $DatabasePermission  = $DB.DatabasePermissions.GetByRole($Role.ID)
          
          # Get the SSAS cubes within the database
          foreach ($Cube in $DB.Cubes)
          {
               $CubePermission = $Cube.CubePermissions.GetByRole($Role.ID) 
               
               $ItemResult = New-Object System.Object
               $ItemResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name DatabaseName -value $DB.Name
               $ItemResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name RoleName -value $Role.Name
               $ItemResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name DatabaseAdministrator -value $DatabasePermission.Administer
               $ItemResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name DatabaseProcess -value $DatabasePermission.Process
               $ItemResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name DatabaseReadDefinition -value $DatabasePermission.ReadDefinition
               $ItemResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name CubeName -value $Cube.Name
               $ItemResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name CubeRead -value $CubePermission.Read.value__
               $ItemResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name CubeWrite -value $CubePermission.Write.value__
               $ItemResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name CubeProcess -value $CubePermission.Process
               $ItemResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name RoleMembers -value ($Role.Members | Select -ExpandProperty Name)
               
               $Result +=$ItemResult
          }
     }
}
$lista = $Result | Select DatabaseName, RoleName,  DatabaseAdministrator, DatabaseProcess, DatabaseReadDefinition, `
CubeName, CubeRead, CubeWrite, CubeProcess,RoleMembers | format-table * -Wrap -AutoSize | Out-String

$lista
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).